# .gitlab-ci.yml for .NET framework

Tags: .net, gitlab-ci

How can I configure `Gitlab CI` to build `.NET` Framework applications?

The `.gitlab-ci.yml` should probably look like:

```
image: microsoft/dotnet:latest

stages:
  - build
  #- test

build_job:
  stage: build
  script:
  - 'echo building...'
  - '"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" /p:Configuration=Release /t:Clean;Build ConsoleApp1.sln '
```

Comment: Fixex tags and format.

Comment: Is it standard .net or .net core?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure yet if you want to build standard .net or .net core. If the latter is the case I hope that this can point you in the correct direction.

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2

stages:
  - build

build-job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - dotnet build ConsoleApp1.sln
```

All possible `dotnet` invocations can be found here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet?tabs=netcore21

An example repository can be found here: https://gitlab.com/zanseb/build-dotnet-example

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Because you mentioned .NET Framework in your title and msbuild in your question, I'm assuming classic .NET. You'll need Windows to build this. This can be either

- a GitLab runner running on a Windows machine where you have access to msbuild (so a Windows-installed GitLab runner with a [`Shell` executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/shell.html) that can execute PowerShell)
- a GitLab runner running on a Windows machine with the [`docker-windows`](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html) executor so that it can download a Windows Docker container

What the config then looks like for me is something like this:

```
default:
  tags:
    - windows

build-job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - |
        Write-Host "Building solution"
        $msbuild = "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe"
        &$msbuild MyApplication.sln
```

The `tags` ensures it is picked up by a Windows runner, so you'll have to have a Windows runner available and configure it to pick up this tag.

Then it's just a matter of setting up the script correctly so that it builds your solution. In my case, .NET 4.8 is installed on the machine.